# Windows 7 System hangs at login screen

Tags: windows-7, norton-internet-security

After I fixed a boot problem ( [How to fix winload.exe is missing or corrupt issue on Windows 7 startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/113187/how-to-fix-winload-exe-is-missing-or-corrupt-issue-on-windows-7-startup) ), I ran into this hang problem again.

My system hanged at login screen, i.e. where I was supposed to input the password. I could not even move my mouse.

Then I tried these steps below:

1. Started system with 'Safe Mode with Network Connection'. It worked fine. No hangs.
2. Disabled 'Startup Items' in 'msconfig' and restart. System hanged again.
3. Use 'Diagnostic startup' in 'msconfig' and restart. System hanged again.
4. Then I tried to uninstall 'Norton Internet Security 2010' in Safe Mode as Step 1. System hanged quickly after startup of uninstallation process.

I am not quite sure if NIS 2010 is related to this problem. But how can I uninstall it manually? or how can I just disable its system driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to disable the norton drivers and inspect all other startup items...

Comment: Thanks. I used this tool to disable all items from Symantec. Now my system works fine.
But can you kindly tell me how I can remove NIS 2010? It hangs again if I try the uninstallation program from Control Panel.

Comment: follow this: http://www.symantec.com/norton/support/kb/web_view.jsp?wv_type=public_web&docurl=20090910004050EN